# Remove everything between two quote tags

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

A text contains some quotes with a random number.

See:

```
$string = '[quote=&quot;Member123&quot;:hk1f9ynv]This is the quote Text  and we want remove it.[/quote:hk1f9ynv]

Here is the anwser to the quote. 

[quote:hk1f9ynv]Here is another quote, we want remove it too.[/quote:hk1f9ynv]

Thank you very much. Good job!';
```

The Number: hk1f9ynv is stored in the DB and is random.

**Output should look like:**

*Here is the answer to the quote. Thank you very much. Good job!*

I tried many solutions on stack. Nothing seems to work. example:

```
preg_replace('/\[[^>]*\]/', '', $string); 
preg_replace('\[/?abc.*?\]', '', $string);
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try something like `preg_replace('\[/?quote\:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\]', '', $string);` I'm not sure about '/' you might need to use a '\' too. Obvisouly you can replace 'quote' by what you want.

Comment: tried both options. result -->   Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in

Comment: Oh sorry! I forgot to add '/' at then end / begin. You must add it.

Comment: like this? preg_replace('\[/?quote\:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\]/', '', $string);

Comment: No, like this: `preg_replace('/\[/?quote\:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\]/', '', $string);`?

Comment: Unknown modifier '?'

Comment: '?' isn't in the string, it was just to finish my sentence.

Comment: yes I saw that. It still comes. I think from the ? before the first quote

Comment: Indeed, but I don't know why.. Casimir helped you so it's ok now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible approaches with preg_replace:

The first one ignores the id of quote tags:

```
~\[quote\b [^]]* ]
 [^[]*+
 (?: (?:\[ (?!/?quote\b) | (?R) ) [^[]* )*+
 \[/quote\b [^]]* ]~x
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/zA5hS4/1)

The second captures the id and uses it to find the closing tag:

```
~\[quote\b [^]:]* : (?<id>[^:]*) ]
 .*? # or: [^[]*+ (?:\[(?!\[/quote\b [^]:]* : \g{id} ])[^[]*)*+
 \[/quote\b [^]:]* : \g{id} ]~xs
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/zA5hS4/2)

These two patterns are designed to handle nested tags.

Comment: both work like a charm. thank you very much. Which one is best to choose?

Comment: @user2057781: In my opinion, the first one. Because it needs less steps than the second one and works even if there's no id.

Comment: saved my day @casimir. Very nice! :) thanks again :) - and all others too for invest your time.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just take the start tag using $string.substr(0, $string.indexOf("]"))

Comment: thank you. echo $string.substr(0, $string.indexOf("]")); gives --> Call to undefined function indexof()

Comment: don't know what it is in php. maybe instr or index

Comment: `indexOf` is `strpos()` in php: [information here](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strstr.php)